# Display java application errors in terminal/console

Tags: java, intellij-idea, terminal, console

As you know when we building applications we get Errors/Exceptions such as NullPointerException etc. on IDE Console (I'm using IntelliJ IDEA).

I want to display those errors simultaneously in my Mac Terminal for larger view so I don't have to horizontally scroll IDE Console every time when I get big errors.

I don't want to run my applications from Terminal with commands (java class...)

I want to run from my IDE and all texts which is going down(errors,exceptions infos.) will reflect to Terminal.

So is there a any log file that i can look into? How can I achieve this?

Comment: What kind of application are you developing? Generally speaking, there is no log file that is written by all Java applications. However, if you're building a Web application and running it under an application server, the errors will be written to the application server log, which you can view in the terminal.

Comment: I know that.Generally i develop web applications in Tomcat but if i gonna use embeded Jetty server for my development how can i see those errors.My question is is there any general solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Logs tab of an IntelliJ IDEA run configuration, there is an option "Save console output to a file". You can use that to save the output of your application to a file and to view it in the terminal. [image: screenshot]